# Firebase multiple where queries in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I want to filter data that comes from Firebase using where queries in Angular. But filter only works when I enter both values. But I want filter to work also when there are only one value how can I do it?

```
getRequest(id, data) {
    console.log(data);
    return this.firestore
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(id)
      .collection('requests', (x) =>
        x
          .where('trace_id', '==', data.traceID)
          .where('status', '==', +data.status)
      )
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback to the collection method is a normal method, so you can use normal JavaScript constructs to get what you want. For example:

```
.collection('requests', (x) => {
  let result: Query<DocumentData> = x;
  if (data.traceID) result = result.where('trace_id', '==', data.traceID);
  if (data.status)  result = result.where('status', '==', +data.status);
  return result;
)
```

Comment: this solution throwing error Type 'Query<DocumentData>' is not assignable to type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>'.ts(2322)

Comment: Hmm... it looks like TypeScript's type inference is getting in the way here. I gave the variable an explicit type now to circumvent the type inference.